# How to remove validation text from my MVC controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I added validation on my Model, like this:

```
                [Required]
                [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 4)]
                [Display(Name = "Users code")]
                public string UserCode { get; set; }
```

As you can see guys, when I'm creating new user, field UserCode must be filled, and minimum length of characters into the field is 4 and max is 60.

And here is how it looks when I try to skip this field or insert less than 4 characters..
[image]

As you can see guys there is a text The string must be a field bla bla bla, how could I hide or remove that? I really don't need it

Comment: Look on your .cshtml - remove `@Html.ValidationMessageFor...`

Comment: You might also like to change `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`

Comment: Why don't you want it? How would your users know its invalid if your don't tell them.

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you can see input became red if something is wrong with validation, and that's reason I don't need message also, highlighting input to red is enought for now :)

Comment: @freedomn-m that solved issue so you might post it as answer so I might accept it as you were fastest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation text under inputs is added automatically by the MVC scaffolding and will have an entry in the .cshtml like:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor...
```

simply removing this line from the .cshtml will remove it from the output.

---

**As a caveat**: this will then mean the user won't know exactly what's wrong with the input.  It could be that the field is required, or in the wrong format.  In this case, a user code of 3 characters may appear to be correct, but they'll still get the error.

There should be some other mechanism for displaying the reason, either with a custom notification or eg changing the ValidationSummary to not exclude property errors (naughty Microsoft using negative terms requiring double negatives... tsk), eg change

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

to

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

---

**BONUS**

If you find yourself removing these manually, you can edit the Code Template t4 to remove them.  Copy the edit.cs.t4 from program files (I'll leave you to find it) to a folder in your project with the same structure, specifically:

```
/CodeTemplates/MvcView/Edit.cs.t4
```

add change it as required.  This will then be used when you scaffold an edit page.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your error message of your field from .cshtml page :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off client-side unobtrusive validation for a single field by adding a data-val='false' attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { data_val = "false" })
```

This will override the `data-val='true'` attribute that MVC adds due to any System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes. The HTML element will still be decorated with other validation attributes (e.g. data-val-required) but they won't have any effect.

> (Note the underscore in data_val above. MVC automatically converts
>   underscores to hyphens in anonymous type properties, so data_val
>   becomes data-val when rendering the HTML)